# What is the attack bonus when falling/jumping?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

When you are falling, or otherwise moving downwards, what is your [attack bonus](http://twitter.com/#!/notch/status/75455902018310144)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

0.5 heart.

```
EntityPlayer.java:
...
    public void attackTargetEntityWithCurrentItem(Entity entity) {
        int i = inventory.getDamageVsEntity(entity);
        if(i > 0) {
            if(motionY < 0)
                i++;
...
```